# Pymongo - how to filter nested array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have dataset like this:

```
{
  "level_1": "A",
  "cols": ["A", "B"],
  "table": [
    {country: "NO", population: 400, color: "red"},
    {country: "AE", population: 100, color: "red"},
    {country: "OT", population: 200, color: "blue"},
  ]
},
{
  "level_1": "B",
  "cols": ["A", "B"],
  "table": [
    {country: "AL", population: 400, color: "red"},
    {country: "AR", population: 100, color: "green"},
    {country: "YU", population: 200, color: "red"},
    {country: "AX", population: 200, color: "red"},
  ]
}
```

I want to filter out all the data based on the nested filter so the result is the following:

```
{
  "level_1": "A",
  "cols": ["A", "B"],
  "table": [
    {country: "NO", population: 400, color: "red"},
    {country: "AE", population: 100, color: "red"},
  ]
},
{
  "level_1": "B",
  "cols": ["A", "B"],
  "table": [
    {country: "AL", population: 400, color: "red"},
    {country: "YU", population: 200, color: "red"},
    {country: "AX", population: 200, color: "red"},
  ]
}
```

Basically leave only values in the nested array that have `color: "red"` and population equalling 200.
I tried using this:

```
db.collection.find([{table.color: "red"}, {table.population: 200}])
```

However it seems to return all of the values, no filtering works at all.
I checked other questions but they dont seem to solve this at all.

Comment: The `find` query/filter is to locate documents.  If you want to alter the document, you could project what you want.  Have a look at [`"$filter"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZU-jHgcAM19

Comment: @R2D2 looks fine, is it possible to use multiple conditions?

Comment: Afcourse  @AlexT

Comment: Have you tried to extend @R2D2's solution @Alex T?  The link from @R2D2 works fine for the original question. It can be trivially modified to support your additional request of `and population equalling 200`

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/9tw8MxCf2Fq